# PostgreSQL : SSL with TCP connections

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am trying to configure SSL communication for PostgreSQL.
I have a self-signed cerificate and I am following these instructions as specified in URL "http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ssl-tcp.html".

When I configure SSL with a self signed certificate, as per the documentation the server will prompt for a (private key's password) password when it start-up.
My PostgreSQL is installed as a windows service.So, I want my service to start without any user intervention. Is there a way to configure private key password so that my database service starts up normally.

Comment: Did you try to remove passphrase from certificate?

Comment: Yes, if we use a certificate with no password for private key, the postgresql starts normally.But, I am using Java's Keytool and it does not allow you to generate a certificate without a password. OpenSSL will allow you to do so, but as far as possible I don't want to use 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a bad idea even if it were possible.  You get very little additional security by putting both the key and the passphrase where the server process can see it.  This adds a false sense of security and a greater chance of bad things happening.

If your tool won't give you a passphraseless key, use a different tool.